# How to get store category url in Magento 1.8?

Tags: category, geturl

how can I get the store **category url**?

I know I can get the store direct url like this,

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="contacts"}}">Contact Us</a>
```

But what about the store's categories?

The categories I have in my store, such as 'Wines', 'Food', etc, so if I do this,

```
{{store direct_url="wines"}} // returns http://mystore/wine
```

I will get a 404 error page. Because the url should be like this,

`http://mystore/wine.html`

Any idea?

Comment: Simply try: {{store direct_url="wine.html"}}

Comment: actually I need to remove `.html` from my url - is it possible?

Comment: Go to admin->System->Configuration ->Catalog ->Search Engine Optimizations -> delete “.html” from Product URL Suffix and Category URL Suffix,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the id of the category you get the url using widgets:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml" id_path="category/8"}}
```

the value of `template` can be:

1. `catalog/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml`
2. `catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a clean way to get a category URL w/o trailing slash.

I would do it like this:

```
{{store direct_url=""}}wines.html
```